# How to Auto Resize , UIView Outlet in UIViewController in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have .xib with UIView size set to w Any  and h Any. The problem is it does not resize properly. I am also using auto layout with the .xib. At present there is only one view (which is the view outlet for the UIViewController).

I am looking for the view to resize for screens with multiple resolution ex: 640 * 480, 720 * 480 , 1024 * 768, etc.

So, if do the following, the resize dose not work.

```
Controller *myController=[[Controller alloc]  initWithNibName:@"Controller" bundle:nil];
[myBaseView addSubview:myController.view];
```

I also tried to set the "Content Compression Resistance Priority" to 1, which will allow it to resize with less resistance.

[image]

But, the following works

```
UIView *aTestView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myBaseView.bounds]];
 [myBaseView addSubview: aTestView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set frame of your viewcontroller's view:

```
Controller *myController=[[Controller alloc]  initWithNibName:@"Controller" bundle:nil];
[myController.view setFrame:superViewFrame];
[myBaseView addSubview:myController.view];
```

Comment: This is easy. But, I thought autoresize will take consideration of the baseView frame and resize.

Comment: When you use addSubview method to present your view which has autolayout on, it doesn't layout with right sizes the view to match parent sizes, as in the case when presentViewController or pushViewController would be used.